# Drawing on dimensional planes

Tags: dimension-theory-analysis

I was thinking of a really weird thing in my science class today. I was thinking if 2-Dimensional figures could draw in their own plane or "piece of paper". I eventually ruled that they cannot as there is no third dimension to put the "lead" on the plane. I think the same would not work as well in a 1-Dimensional plane as well. However when it comes to 3-D are we drawing in our own dimension? As in all 3-Dimensions of the world at the same time. Would it be physically possible for us to do so? And would that be the same for 4-D or 5-D as well. I think the answer is that for a person in the $n^{\text{th}}$ dimension they can only "interact" with at most $n-1$ dimensions at a time. Is there a mathematical proof for this? (Sorry if this question is bad, or not really related to math)

Comment: Couldn't you have a point move and leave a trace as it moves? That would seem to be possible in 2 dimensions, and even in 1-dimensional space. So, unless you define 'drawing' in such a way that it would have to involve a 3-dimensional action, I think this is quite possible.

Comment: Oh yeah that's true! Then what about 3-Dimensions?

Comment: Well, we normally (that is, in our 3-dimensional world) think of 'drawing' as putting a 'trace' on a sheet of paper ... which is what we rgard as 2-dimensional. Hence, I think, your hypothesis that in n-dimenional space we would draw in (n-1) dimensional space. But, note that even that sheet of paper, and hence its trace, has a location in 3-dimenional space. That line that I draw on a sheet of paper therefore has a $(x,y,z)$ beiginning and end. So, drawing in n-dimensional space seems to involve putting a trace in n-dimensional space, compatiable with my earlier comment

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AQgI2-h7uUQ

Comment: Would that be considered drawing in all 3 dimensions at once though?, wait no it is